# Using a baked position as new start position

Tags: scripting

My problem: I have a (probably insane) model with about 30000 shapes. I want to drop the entire thing using rigid body physics. I am not really interested in the animation as such, nor is it important that the simulation is 100% correct, I just want the final pile of shapes.

The problem is that I can't bake all of it in one go (blender crashes far before the bake is finished).

I am currently trying to bake some frames, then use the baked position as my new starting position, and bake again from there.
I use the following script, and it seemed to work when I tried it on just a few objects, but it does nothing as far as I can see when I run it on my big model.
Script:

```
import bpy

def usebake(frame = 20):
  bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)
  i = 0
  for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    i = i+1
    obj.location = obj.matrix_world.to_translation()
    obj.rotation_quaternion = obj.matrix_world.to_quaternion()
    #obj.rotation_euler = obj.matrix_world.to_euler()
  print(i)
```

The process I have used is as follows:
Bake -> run script -> free bake -> bake new

Am I doing something wrong?
Alternatively, is there another way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out all my objects had an animation linked to them for some reason (I'm guessing it is because I had been experimenting with keyframes as another way to solve my question, but I'm not sure). I reverted to a backup file without the linked animations, and it works just fine now.